# How to check git and github post/creation date?

Tags: git, github

I would like to know how to check git init date and time and also where is this information on github project. With github project I don't want to go to commit tab and then browse to last page even if I can calculate it like [number of commits] / [commits per page].

Comment: Keep in mind that the timestamp of `git init` isn't recorded anywhere and that the two timestamps recorded for commits aren't necessarily useful or accurate for your purposes. If you explain why you need this information you might get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all this with `git log`. To jump to the first commit, press `G` (capital "g"). Or you could reverse the listing to show the first commit at the top with:

```
git log --reverse
```

If you want to know really just the date you could of course `grep` it too:

```
git log --reverse | head -n 4 | grep ^Date
```

On GitHub look at the **Commits** tab on the project's front page.

To jump to the first commit, I don't think there's a user interface. There might be an interesting hack though. But in the worst case, you can hack the pagination URL. For example, if you count the number of commits per page, it's 35. And the front page of the project tells you how commits you have. For example in my project with 541 commits, I can calculate that the initial commit will be on page = 541 / 35 = 15.45 = 16, so I can jump to a URL like this:

```
https://github.com/user/project/commits/master?page=16
```

Comment: ```git log``` gives me only list of logs from the beginning. If there 100000 logs then it's hard to scroll it. How can I get the first (initial) one?

Comment: On commit tab I see similar situation like on ```git log```. I need manually click through all pages using "Older >>" button. There's no way to do it in one "shot". Is it?

Comment: git date is better to grep: ```git log --reverse | grep Date | head -1```. But solution for github is annoying. I'm very often interesting when repo was created initially and this is harder then it supposed to be. But thanks for you reply anyway.

Comment: There is another SEMIway to do it. I've send support request to github itself and this is what they reply: _"A quick way of getting this information without using the GtiHub web interface is using the following API call and checking the created_at field:

https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo

So for the repository in your screenshot, the API call would be:

https://api.github.com/repos/block8/phpci"_

 *..and then search for **created_at**

Comment: I still missing created date on every github project page

Comment: Going to the last page doesn't give you want you want, or it's just that it's not easy enough? If GitHub support can't give you a better answer then I think this is the end of the line, ain't it.